# Prevent specified HTML elements

Tags: php, html, doctrine-orm, tinymce-4

I want to implement a small ticket system.

On the frontend I want to use the WYSIWYG editor tinyMCE with features like strong and table etc.
I want to prevent other elements to get into my database like script input etc.
Do you know a PHP library where I can exclude all other elements or allow only the elements tinyMCE create?

On the backend I want to use doctrine - so SQL injections should be turned away through this 
or am I wrong?

Comment: I would go the other way. Build a dom tree and go top->down through that tree (recursive) and kick all subtrees with an not-explicit-allowed root-element (or - if you want it that way - an explicit disallowed root-element).

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use a different WYSIWYG strategy. Writing to the DOM user input in HTML has a very high risk of XSS injection.

I'd recommand using a WYSIWYG Markdown editor (like [SimpleMDE](https://simplemde.com/)), and storing the user input in Markdown format in your database.
Then you can use a PHP librairie (like [Parsedown](http://parsedown.org/)) to parse the Markdown content and write the equivalent HTML content.
Markdown has much less options (only text formatting pretty much), which reduces the chances of XSS attacks.

Moreover, you should probably implement some server-side checking on the user content, as you can never be sure that your user used your WYSIWYG editor to submit a ticket.

Comment: Thank you, but is it not possible to do somithing like this before writing into the database: `strip_tags($_POST['message'], '<p><span><strong><h3><h4><h5><sub><sup><em><ul><ol><li><a><table><tr><td>')`

Comment: It is, but then any HTML tag would be ascaped, including `<strong>` and other formatting tags.

Comment: But with the second parameter I thought that I allow these tags in it?

Comment: Correct ! But I'd rather use the Markdown approach, as it is strongly recommanded to avoid storing user-input HTML in your database. Their can be some tricks that would allow to run unwanted tags such as iframe or script.

Comment: OK, now it's clear to me. Do you know how it is possible to edit directly in the preview window with simpleMDE like Jira "Visual"?

For some users, it can be confusing to see the format parameter (*) in their text input.

For what reason should I use TinyMCE instead if it is not possible to send formatted text without HTML tags?

Comment: I haven't used it, but I'm sure there are plenty of other WYSIWYG MD editors out there that can fit your needs !